# Downloading Universal package from Azure Artifacts locally

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Is there an easy way to download the latest Universal package contents without running all the commands using the Azure CLI ?

In my project, we are storing the Installer generated from pipeline (of a .NET application) as a Universal Package in the Azure Artifacts. This is a ZIP file containing the Installer.

While it was easy to download the Zip file in TeamCity, it's a headache in Azure Devops. 30 people in my team has to download the Installer every week and we are looking for an easy way to download this (at least the latest universal package).

Answer (score -1):

> Is there an easy way to download the latest Universal package contents without running all the commands using the Azure CLI ?

To download the Universal package in Azure Devops, we could use the [Universal packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops) task：

[image]

We could use wildcard in the **Version** option to get the highest version with major version.

BTW, there is an user voice about [use the REST API to download the Universal package](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/616820/download-universal-package-rest-api.html). If there is a REST API available, the ERST API will also be a good choice. You could vote that that up and leave your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I believe this will work only in a Pipeline task. In this case, the download path of the Universal package will be on the agent running the pipeline, correct ? What if I want to download it to my current PC which is not actually an agent configured with the pipeline ?

Comment: @Abinash, I saw that you wrote **Downloading Universal package in Azure Devops** in the title, so I thought you could accept to download the Universal package in the pipeline. If you want to download the package locally, as I wrote later in the answer, because there is no REST API yet Support, we can only use CLI at this moment.

Comment: @Abinash, Thanks, but just I said in the answer and comment, I am afraid there is such out of way to resolve this, since there is no REST API to download the Universal package, if you do not want use CLI :(.

Comment: The question literally says LOCALLY (i.e. not in a remote agent)